# How should I save a dictionary database with java?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

When I google "how to make a dictionary", it gives me a great measure of the explanation of "make", which is very helpful. But I need something else, so I put this question here.

I want to make a small project. I want to make a dictionary with java or android. But I don't know how should I organize the words. I have considered a JSON file, a XML file or I can also simply output all the words as ojbects into a file. Could anyone please give me some adivce?

Comment: You suggest you to read about databases. SQLite, MySQL etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to be able to read (quickly) values from your dictionary, and maybe update values or create new values then I suggest that you store your dictionary in a Database.  For a simple Java database I suggest that you use an embedded Derby Database.

see http://db.apache.org/derby/